# Why Google analytics AVG Session duration is wrong?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics for tracking my visitors.

In recent days I started to use live support system on my website. I can see on the live support system the time the users spend on the site. Since most of my articles are longer than 1500 words, users spend a lot of time on the site.

The average session time on the live support system is over 10 minutes, but Google Analytics showing it is under 2 minutes.

I know that Google analytics is wrong. What could be the reason for this? Why does Google analytics show average session duration incorrectly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming

Comment: @Max Can not I ask a question for help on a topic? Instead of voting negative, you can try to help. We are not the enemy. I'm trying to get help. You can guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an user lands in your page, reads the article and leaves the website without making any interaction that sends an hit to Analytics (for example clicking on a link to change page of your website) the time on page will be 0.
Analytics calculates the average time in page based on the difference between the first and last hits occurred on that page.

Try to send events on scroll to Analytics (example 25%, 50%, ...) and you'll see that the time on page will begin to be representative.

Comment: Thank you for help, Michele! Will avg duration time change when I do this? Is this a good way to measure real time? And can I use this library for this? https://github.com/robflaherty/jquery-scrolldepth

Comment: To track scroll interaction you can use any script that does it, as long as you send the events to the established percentages of scrolling.

I can't tell you that the time on page will correspond to what you detect with your system, but it will certainly make more sense.
If you want you can also send an event to the exit intent, in order to have more coverage of interaction.

Comment: Thank you again! I installed the script. There was a noticeable increase in the average session duration. But I think there is another problem. The bounce rate is very low. Almost 20%. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes it is normal, because the bounce rate is the effect of who enters in your site and exits (or expires the session) without doing other interaction tracked, however without tracking any other interaction in a page (especially in pages like articles where an user reads and goes away) you will have a bounce rate even also for users that enter in your page, read your article for 20 minutes and then exit. So I suggest you to evaluate when you think it's an acceptable minimum scroll level to consider as an interaction if you want to also balance a more significant bounce rate.

Answer (score -2):

Please refer this link https://www.studentcpu.com/2020/03/google-analytics-important-kpi-monitor.html. you will get answer for your query. In this website it is clearly explain about most of site admin misunderstood between avg session duration time and avg time on page.

Avg Session Duration -Multiple Page Avg Time-Macro view

Avg Time on Page - Single Page Time-Micro view